# Generic way of creating XML files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, generics

I am trying to create a class which saves/reads multiple XML files using LINQ and Genertics.

**I am looking for generic way of saving XMl files of multiple type (i.e data in them)**

Every XML file will have following format

```
<ROOT>
     <!-- First Element/First Row -->
     <NODE>
           <COL1>Some value</COL1>
           .....  
           <COLn>Some value</COLn>
     </NODE>
     .........
     <!-- Nth Element = nth row -->
     <NODE>
           <COL1>Some value</COL1>
           .....  
           <COLn>Some value</COLn>
     </NODE>
</ROOT>
```

Every file will have a different ROOT, NODE and COLx. The Number of columns and data in them depends on the Multi-Dim array input. This input array also gives the number of NODES tags in xml (elements in array).

A method to save an XML file looks like

```
public void SaveFirstXmlFile()
{
    XElement xdoc = new XElement("ThisDocsRoot");
    //Iterate for number of rows(elements of data)            
    for (int nodes= 1; nodes<= NUMBER_OF_NODES; nodes++)
    {
        xdoc.Add(new XElement(row,
                              new XElement("Col 1", "Some Value"),
                              new XElement("Col 2", "Some Value"),
                              new XElement("Col 3", "Some Value")
                     ));
    } 
    xdoc.Save("/Path/To/XML/File");
}
```

I wanted to tweak this method so that it works for multiple XML files.I don't know if it is correct way of doiung it, but I strated creating CLasses which define the root,node,columns and path for the XML file. and The data comes from Multi-Dim Arrays created by some other classes.

```
private class AClassforSomeXMLFile
{
    private readonly String _root;
    private readonly String _row;
    private readonly String[] _columns;
    private readonly String _exportPath;

    public UsageData()
    {

        _exportPath = string.Format(@"{0}\xyz.xml",Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));

        _root = "ROOT";
        _row = "NODE";
        _columns = new string[]
            {
                "COL1","COL2", "COL3","COL4",
            };
    }

    public string ROOT {  get { return _root; } }

    public string ROW { get { return _row; } }

    public string[] COLS  { get { return _columns; }}

    public string EPATH { get { return _exportPath; }}
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would require generics -- just replace your literals in `SaveFirstXmlFile` with the values from `AClassforSomeXMLFile`?

Comment: I know, but this will only for one class, and I have at-least 5 different types of XML files to make. I want one method which works for all of these.

Comment: Can you give one more example of another type of xml file you want to make? It is not very clear what is the difference between these xml files. Is it only names of nodes, like ROOT can become AAA, NODE can become ITEM, etc? Or difference lies in xml structure?

Comment: If you have any control over the format look to replace COL1-COLn with a series of COL elements and it becomes trivial to solve it with XML serialization.

Comment: @Alexander The difference between the XML's files lies in the Elements i.e name ot the Root,Nodes and the number of Columns. See my comment to Sam I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add constructor to AClassforSomeXMLFile class, to populate root, row and columns values, and then pass instance of definition to your SaveFirstXmlFile function:

```
private class XmlDefinition
{
    public string ROOT { get;set; }
    public string ROW { get;set; }
    public string[] COLS  { get;set; }
    public string EPATH { get;set; }
}


void Foo()
{
  var employeeDefinition = new XmlDefinition 
  { 
    ROOT = "Employees", 
    ROW = "Employee", 
    COLS = new[] { "Name", "Address", "Department", "Salary" },
    EPATH = string.Format(@"{0}\employee.xml",Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath))
  };

  SaveFirstXmlFile(employeeDefinition); //save employees

  var productDefinition = new XmlDefinition 
  { 
    ROOT = "Products", 
    ROW = "Product", 
    COLS = new[] { "Name", "Description", "Cost" },
    EPATH = string.Format(@"{0}\products.xml",Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath))
  };

  SaveFirstXmlFile(productDefinition); //save products
}

public void SaveFirstXmlFile(AClassforSomeXMLFile definition)
{
    XElement xdoc = new XElement(definition.ROOT);
    //Iterate for number of rows(elements of data)            
    for (int nodes = 1; nodes <= NUMBER_OF_NODES; nodes++)
    {
        var cols = from c in definition.COLS select new XElement(c, "Some Value");
        xdoc.Add(new XElement(definition.ROW, cols.ToArray()));
    } 
    xdoc.Save(definition.EPATH);
}
```

Comment: What about the type of definition. It is AClassforSomeXMLFile above but it can different for different XML file, so first option is to use 2 parameters an Enum (to indicate the Class for XML) and definition of type Object. Object will be parsed to its type e.g AClassforSomeXMLFile in this case based on the Enum. Is there any other way to do this which is more generic i.e I don't have cast types or use Enums etc

Comment: Expanded my sample a bit. You don't need multiple classes - one is enough (I renamed it to XmlDefinition). You can specify your required names in class constructor, and then pass same type, but with different contents to your 'save' method. As an extension to this solution, and to save on typing, you can derive custom 'ProductXmlDefinition', 'EmployeeXmlDefinition' classes, which do initialization in constructor, and you can just create new instance, and pass it without filling with data. Method would still accept base class type, XmlDefinition.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand the ask here, but It looks like it might be satisfied if you format your XML like this

```
 <NODE>
       <COL>Some value</COL>
       .....  
       <COL>Some value</COL>
 </NODE>
```

and then you can read all your `COL`s into a list

```
XElement xdoc = new XElement("ThisDocsRoot");
List<XElement> Cols = xdoc.Elements("COL").ToList();
```

Comment: The ROOT element, Node Elements and Columns will be different. It is similar to different tables in a database. for Example If I am representing employees in XML I will have my Root as Employees(tabel name), Each Node as Employee (each row in the table) and COL as Name, Address, Department, Salary etc (columns in the table). Similarly I can have other XML files to represent Customer, Product etc. I hope you understand what I am intending to do have in my XML files. If I am correct you are creating and List from from XML, but I have write it to XML.

Comment: @KhurramMajeed the `Descendants()` method might be able to help you with that